# How can i do a list of objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am using react, and i need to add files in a list.

```
this.state = { 
    some: {
         names: [],
         keys: 0
    } 
    file: {
       images: [] 
    } 

}
newSome = () => {
    const some = {
        ...this.state.some,
        ['name'] = 'inputed name',
        [keys] = this.state.some.keys++    
}

handleChange = (field,key) => event => {
       const file = {...this.state.file}
        file['images'].push({[key] : event.target.files[event.target.files.length-1]})
        this.setState({file}) 

}

render(){
    const {key} = this.state.some
    return (
       <input type='file' onChange={this.handleChange('images', key)}/>
   )

}
```

i have a `dictionary` that has as "name with image" and "name without image". in `images`, i have the images of names. For example: `name['maria', 'joao', renato]`, and joao doesn't have image... so in images i have `images[{0: file0},{2: file1}]`. When i load a image, in first operation, it works, but in second doesn't work, and appear the error `TypeError: file.images.push is not a function`. What i have to do?

Comment: YOu have a typo. key will always be a empty string. So you are trying to push {'': 'imageName'}. If you can post a stackblitz solution, someone can help to debug.

Comment: 1. ``<input type='file' onChange={() => this.handleChange('images', key)}/>``
2. ``const file = {...this.state.file}`` you are doing shallow copy here, you should do ``const file = {images: [...this.state.file.images, {[key] : event.target.files[event.target.files.length-1]}]}; this.setState({file}) ``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
state = {
    some: {
      names: [],
      key: ""
    },
    file: {
      images: []
    }
  };

  handleChange = (field, key) => event => {
    const { files } = event.target;
    const file = {
      images: [...this.state.file.images, { [key]: files[files.length - 1] }]
    };
    this.setState({ file });
  };

  render() {
    const { key } = this.state.some;
    return <input type="file" onChange={this.handleChange("images", key)} />;
  }
```